# Difference in interquartile range values between R and MATLAB

Tags: r, matlab

I have a column of data but it appears that the interquartile range caluclated on R and Matlab are different.

Data:

```
a = structure(list(Medication = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 3L,
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 6L, 1L,
0L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L,
3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 0L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 3L,
0L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 3L,
0L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L,
0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -250L), class = "data.frame")
```

On R:

```
 summary(a)
 Medication  
 Min.   :0.00  
 1st Qu.:0.00  
 Median :0.00  
 Mean   :0.86  
 3rd Qu.:1.75  
 Max.   :7.00
```

On MATLAB:

```
prctile(a,75)
ans =
     2
```

The 3rd quantile/75th percentile is different between the 2 software, but the mean and median are the same. Does the calculation for interquartile range differ between the 2 packages?

Comment: R offers nine different types of quantiles, see `help("quantile")`. Find out which one Matlab uses and specify the same type in R (see `help("IQR")`).

Comment: From Matlab's `help quantile`: to compute `quantile(X,N)`, 1) The sorted values in `X` are taken as the (0.5/N), (1.5/n), ..., ((N-0.5)/N) quantiles. 2) Linear interpolation is used to compute quantiles for probabilities between (0.5/N) and ((N-0.5)/N). 3) The minimum or maximum values in `X` are assigned to quantiles for probabilities outside that range.`